# Way to detect PHP interactive mode

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to detect whether PHP script is being executed inside PHP's interactive mode.

I have a `bootstrap.php` file that I `include` in some scripts, but also use when launching PHP in interactive mode to get a REPL playground for stuff initialized in that file (mainly for exploring database via ORM):

```
php -d auto_prepend_file=bootstrap.php -a
```

I'd like to execute some code when it's being run from `php -a` — define few useful globals, show welcome help message.

`PHP_SAPI` reports `cli` in both cases.

I'd like something that:

```
php -d auto_prepend_file=bootstrap.php -a
# → true

php -a
include 'bootstrap.php';
# → true

php bootstrap.php
# → false

php file_that_includes_bootstrap.php
# → false

php -r "include 'bootstrap.php';"
# → false

cat bootstrap.php | php
# → should be `false`, but I don't really care about that one
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is a work for debugger, and there is well-designed one: [phpdbg](http://phpdbg.com/)

Comment: The only method I know of is that autoloading doesn't work in interactive mode, but does in cli, maybe you could come up with a test that involves using reflection to try and load a class that's in the autoloader, if the reflector throws an error that the class isn't loaded you're running in interactive mode.

Comment: @AlmaDo `bootstrap.php` sets up Zend+Doctrine application and we use it in interactive mode to test out entities and other classes and methods. I basically just want to display a message saying "There are predefined $app, $serviceManager, $entityManager" globals, feel free to play around". True, phpdbg may be more suitable environment for that than `php -a`, but I don't really want to enforce people to install more things.

Comment: @scragar `bootstrap.php` already defines some (composer's) autoloading and it works, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @AD7six I'm not trying to build an interface, just use the one provided by `php -a`. Running

    php -d auto_prepend_file=bootstrap.php -a

gives me php's console with my application bootstrapped. When used that way, I want to define few helpful global variables and print a welcome message with list of them.

I'm also including `bootstrap.php` in some of the scripts, so I don't want to always display the message.

Comment: @AD7six Like [I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910080/way-to-detect-php-interactive-mode#comment36852989_23910080), it's supposed to be a tool for my team allowing us to for example play around with Doctrine entities: test out relations, setters, getters, create and persist bunch of test data, that kind of things.

I don't see how using boris (or psysh or facebook's phpsh) would make any difference. Besides, these third party REPLs can be detected by looking at `$_SERVER['argv'][0]`.

Comment: @saji you're right - I hadn't seen that comment =). If it's not in the question (and especially if it's a reply to someone asking something different) it's easy to miss. Your above comment indicates you're at least aware of what a REPL is; the question doesn't. Easily addressed though: put info like that _in the question_.

Comment: @AD7six `php -a -d auto_prepend_file=bootstrap.php` is not the same as  `php -a bootstrap.php`. The latter does not interpret file given as the parameter at all.

Yes, I could use some argument as a workaround (or using some `bootstrap-interactive.php` that requires original `bootstra.php` and then prints the message.

…  but that's still a workaround. {;

Guess true detection cannot be done, thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Hah - I hadn't noticed. Please don't forget (unless someone else does) to answer and accept your own answer (not possible, using argv can detect no input file with limitations) as that does seem to be the only answer that applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up with this:

```
'cli' === PHP_SAPI && ! defined('STDOUT')
```

`STDOUT` is not being defined in interactive mode (and when PHP is not ran in CLI, thus checking `PHP_SAPI`). Though I could not find any documentation about it apart from:

> Note:
>
> These constants are not available if reading the PHP script from stdin.
>
> — http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

… which of course is not the case here. So it may change in future releases. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

It might be not perfect workaround, but try to use:

```
var_dump(__FILE__);
```

It gives me "*php shell code*" and it's different then in CLI mode

Comment: I'm not trying to detect interactive mode in the php shell, but inside included file and there `__FILE__` will return my `bootstrap.php`.

But you gave me an idea: checking `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns `-` if php is being executed without any file name given. I think only case when it would return `-` and not be in interactive mode is:

    cat bootstrap.php | php

but I don't care about that use case as it breaks `__FILE__` and I'm actually using it in `bootstrap.php`.

Comment: Almost. Would be great to find a way to also get false on `php -r "require 'bootstrap.php'; /* code */"`